# How to replace more than one word in JavaScript string at a same time?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

I have a javascript string that contains some code like `[Hover on me](Tooltip text)`. I want to convert this code to HTML. `[]` containing text and `()` containing tooltip text

Here is what I want

```
<div class="tooltip">Hover over me
     <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

The string contains multiple tooltip codes and I need to convert each of them to this HTML code

what I am trying

```
<p id="p">blabla [some info](tool) it is text [one](tool) [two] (tool)</p>


var text = document.getElementById('p').innerHTML;
var matches = text.match(/\[(.*?)\]/);
var final = text.match(/\((.*?)\)/);

var res = text.replace(matches[0], "<span>"+matches[1]+"</span>");
var newtext = document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = res;

var ros = newtext.replace(final[0], "<span>"+final[1]+"</span>");
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = ros;

console.log(ros);
```

I know the code is pretty messed up but I need some help with this. I was also trying other code as well but that didn't work either, here is fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mohitchandel/aszv8w93/10/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = document.getElementById('p').innerHTML;


// You may want to validate this loop better.
while( text.indexOf(')') > 0 ) {
    let a = text.slice( text.indexOf('[') + 1, text.indexOf(']') ),
        b = text.slice( text.indexOf('(') + 1, text.indexOf(')') ),
        c = `<div class="tooltip">${ a } <span class="tooltiptext">${ b }</span></div>`;

    text = text.slice( 0, text.indexOf('[') ) + c + text.slice( text.indexOf(')') + 1 );
}
```

This could get you started.

--
RMZ

Comment: You would need to implement it. After the while loop use this => 
document.getElementById('p').innerHTML = text;

Comment: I did it and I am getting the result, thanks a lot